# How do i find all nodes without children (starting from non-root node!) in xpath/R?

Tags: r, xpath, rvest

I know how to find all nodes that dont have a child node:

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

doc <- "https://www.r-bloggers.com/" %>% GET %>% content
leafes <- doc %>% html_nodes(xpath = "//*[not(descendant::*)]")
length(leafes)
```

Now i try the same from nodes that are not the root node:

```
doc <- "https://www.r-bloggers.com/" %>% GET %>% content
tags <- doc %>% html_nodes(xpath = "/html/body/div/div/div/div/h2/a")
nonRootNodeWithChildr <- tags %>% html_nodes(xpath = "..") %>% html_nodes(xpath = "..")
nonRootNodeWithChildr %>% html_nodes(xpath = "*[not(descendant::*)]")
```

I assume that i have to go for `*[]` instead of `//*` to avoid starting at document root, however,
"//" would assure i can also go for the Grand++ children.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
nonRootNodeWithChildr %>% html_nodes(xpath = ".//*[not(descendant::*)]")
```

could be what i was looking for.