# How do i find all "non-parent" nodes in xpath without converting to string?

Tags: r, xml, xpath, rvest

A while ago i answered my question: [How do i find all nodes without children (starting from non-root node!) in xpath/R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60352392/how-do-i-find-all-nodes-without-child-starting-from-non-root-node-in-xpath-r) after some trying.

But sometimes i find exceptions to it:

```
library(magrittr)
library(xml2)
url <- "https://kcsouthern.silkroad.com/epostings/index.cfm?fuseaction=app.jobsearch"
node <- url %>% 
   read_html %>% 
   html_nodes(xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/table/tr[2]")
```

I don´t find all nodes without Children like this:

```
> node %>% html_nodes(xpath = "*//*[not(descendant::*)]")
{xml_nodeset (1)}
[1] <a id="jobTitle_220359" href="index.cfm?fuseaction=app.jobinfo&amp;jobid=…
```

But after converting to string and "re-read" as XML i do:

```
> node %>% 
     toString %>% 
     read_html %>% 
     html_nodes(xpath = "*//*[not(descendant::*)]")
{xml_nodeset (3)}
[1] <td align="center" class="cssSearchResultsBody">220359-021</td>
[2] <a id="jobTitle_220359" href="index.cfm?fuseaction=app.jobinfo&amp;jobid...
[3] <td align="left" class="cssSearchResultsBody">Kansas City, Missouri, United States</td>
```

**Edit: Some further Analysis concerning E. Wiest´s answer:**

Using the XML package:

```
> url %>% 
+   GET %>% 
+   content(as = "text") %>% 
+   XML::htmlParse() %>% 
+   XML::xpathSApply(path = "(//tr[@class='cssSearchResultsHighlight'])[1]//*[not(.//*)]")
[[1]]
<td align="center" class="cssSearchResultsBody">220359-021</td> 

[[2]]
<a id="jobTitle_220359" href="....">SAP HR/Payroll Specialist</a> 

[[3]]
<td align="left" class="cssSearchResultsBody">Kansas City, Missouri, United States</td>
```

Now the equivilant with xml2/rvest: (also seems to work)

```
> url %>% 
+   read_html %>% 
+   html_nodes(xpath = "//tr[@class='cssSearchResultsHighlight'][1]//*[not(.//*)]")
{xml_nodeset (3)}
[1] <td align="center" class="cssSearchResultsBody">220359-021</td>
[2] <a id="jobTitle_220359" href="index.cfm?fuseaction=app.jobinfo&amp;jobid=220359&amp...
[3] <td align="left" class="cssSearchResultsBody">Kansas City, Missouri, United States</td>
```

Problem rather seems to be, that one starts searching from a non-root node?

```
> url %>% 
+   read_html %>% 
+   html_nodes(xpath = "//tr[@class='cssSearchResultsHighlight'][1]") %>% 
+   html_nodes(xpath = "*[not(.//*)]")
{xml_nodeset (2)}
[1] <td align="center" class="cssSearchResultsBody">220359-021</td>
[2] <td align="left" class="cssSearchResultsBody">Kansas City, Missouri, United States</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the problem is related to xml2 or rvest. I have 3 results directly with xpathSApply on my parsed object (htmlParse). XPath :

```
(//tr[@class='cssSearchResultsHighlight'])[1]//*[not(.//*)]
```

Output :

[image: Trucks]

R code :

```
library(httr)
library(XML)
page=GET("https://kcsouthern.silkroad.com/epostings/index.cfm?fuseaction=app.jobsearch")
parsed=htmlParse(content(page,as = "text"))
xpathSApply(parsed,"(//tr[@class='cssSearchResultsHighlight'])[1]//*[not(.//*)]")
```

EDIT 2 : In fact, there's no problem at all. What returns Rvest is just fine. It outputs what the XPath expression means. If we isolate the first tr element, we have.

```
<tr class="cssSearchResultsHighlight">
<td align="center" class="cssSearchResultsBody">220359-021</td>
<td align="left" class="cssSearchResultsBody"><a id="jobTitle_220359" href="index.cfm?fuseaction=app.jobinfo&amp;jobid=220359&amp;source=ONLINE&amp;JobOwner=992452&amp;company_id=16021&amp;version=1&amp;byBusinessUnit=&amp;bycountry=&amp;bystate=&amp;byRegion=&amp;bylocation=&amp;keywords=&amp;byCat=&amp;proximityCountry=&amp;postalCode=&amp;radiusDistance=&amp;isKilometers=&amp;tosearch=no&amp;city=" class="cssSearchResultsBody">SAP HR/Payroll Specialist</a></td>
<td align="left" class="cssSearchResultsBody">Kansas City, Missouri, United States</td> 
</tr>
```

The following code will return 1 result (the a element) from this tr (look for an element, descendant of another element (descendant of the tr), and which has no child) :

```
url %>%
  read_html %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//tr[@class='cssSearchResultsHighlight'][1]") %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "*//*[not(.//*)]")
```

The following code will return 2 results (the first and the third td element) from this tr (look for an element, descendant of the tr, and which has no child)  :

```
url %>%
  read_html %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//tr[@class='cssSearchResultsHighlight'][1]") %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "*[not(.//*)]")
```

The following code will return 3 results (the first and third td element and the a element) from this tr (starting from the tr, look anywhere for an element which has no child)  :

```
url %>%
  read_html %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//tr[@class='cssSearchResultsHighlight'][1]") %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = ".//*[not(.//*)]")
```

[image: XPRvest]
Code n°3 is probably what you're looking for.
Side note : Don't forget to fix your first XPath expression : `/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/table/tr[2]` should be `/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/table//tr[2]`

Comment: thank you for the answer. That is interesting indeed. Sry, i am not that familiar with the XML package, is `parsed`, sthg like: `parsed <- xmlParse(httr::content(httr::GET(url), type = "text"))`?

Comment: thanks you. That helps narrowing down the Problem. I made some further Analysis and added it to my question. It seems to be a Problem to take a non-root node as a "starting Point", which unfortunately is a requirement for me.

Comment: nice. `.` makes perfect sense. Thank you! Idea behind using `//tr` would be to catch all (grand+)children that are of type `tr` as well? Wouldnt their "non-parent" nodes  be included as well if i take `/tr` and then `".//*[not(.//*)]"` ? (just for my interest).